# How do I solve this [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [422]

Tags: flutter, http, dio, flutter-http, dart-http

I am trying to send a form data to a server and it is returning this error back :  `Error Message: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [422]`

How do I solve this issue?

```
          Map<String, String> sentData = {
            'firstname': data['first_name'].trim(),
            'lastname': data['last_name'].trim(),
            'email': data['email'].trim(),
            'phone': data['phone'].trim(),
            'password': data['password'],
            'password_confirmation': data['password_confirmation'],
            'country_id': id.toString(),
          };
          debugPrint('AuthControllerData : Data to Send to Server =  $sentData');

          final formData = dio.FormData.fromMap(sentData);
          var response = await client.HttpClient(resource: 'auth/register').post(data: formData);
          debugPrint('AuthController response: $response');
```

Is this the right way to send the `FormData` and are there better way like the options I have to set while using the [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package to send formdata?

Comment: can i see the full code? where is  the data coming from?

Comment: 'firstname': data['first_name'].trim(), the data variable here

Comment: The data is a Map object that contains some inputs coming frombform fields on the UI. I am doing .trim() here to make data clean before sending it as payload to the request.